# How to implement different user login with login control in asp.net VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good morning everybody, I have meet some trouble in implementing different user login with login control in asp.net, I have tried lots of time and search long long time, but failed.

can you help me? thanks a lot :).

here is my code,
but when I input correct username adn psw, it will redirect to default.aspx though I never let it redirect to default.aspx at all. When I delete the default.aspx I will has error :( I'm almost cry :(

```
protected static Boolean Authentication(string username, string password)
    {           
        string sql = "select StudentID from  Student where StudentID='" + username + "' and psw= '" + password + "'";
        string consqlserver = "server=localhost;user=sa;pwd=6616;database=ustcsse";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = 
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(consqlserver);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con);           

         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;        
         con.Open();
         reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
         if (reader.Read())
             return true;
         else
             return false;
    }

    protected void Login1_Authenticate1(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean blnresult;
        blnresult = false;
        blnresult = Authentication(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
        if (blnresult == true)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
           if(Login1.UserName=="admin")
                Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx", false);
           else
                Response.Redirect("~/welcome.aspx", false);
        }
        else
            e.Authenticated = false;
    }
```

and here is my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" >
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

Comment: And if I add DestinationPageUrl="~/welcome.aspx" in the login.aspx it will redirect to welcome.aspx but it does not what I want, I want to implement a simple different user login only a admin is different